# EXCEL VBA Countifs with dynamic range based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, range, countif

I need help writing a code for a work template. A macro that does a Countifs with dynamic ranges based on cell value:

```
Countifs($H$5:$H$?,$K5,$I$5:$I:$?,N$4)

"**?**" is dynamic based on the value of cell **L5**
```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) for a good start.

Comment: rephrased the question.